# Python Dict sort issue

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am using Python to sort dict items according to the keys. But the output does not  give proper sorting. Can anyone help? Thanks! Here is my code:

```
expected_output= {'13':['0.0'], '14':['8.0'], '99':['1.0'], '100':['1.0'], 
'101':['0.0'], '102':['1.0'], '103':['1.0'], '104':['0.0'], '105':['0.0'], 
'106':['1.0'], '107':['1.0'], '108':['0.0'], '109':['0.0']}
expected_output=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(expected_output.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
print("Expected Output:")
print(expected_output)
```

Output is:

```
Expected Output:
OrderedDict([('108', ['0.0']), ('101', ['0.0']), ('13', ['0.0']), ('104', 
['0.0']), ('105', ['0.0']), ('109', ['0.0']), ('107', ['1.0']), ('102', 
['1.0']), ('106', ['1.0']), ('99', ['1.0']), ('103', ['1.0']), ('100', 
['1.0']), ('14', ['8.0'])])
```

Comment: `t[1]` is the value, not the key. (Also, you've got strings everywhere, and those sort in Unicode-lexicographic order, not numerically.)

Comment: Your expected output does not match your description (`sort according to the keys`). In addition, you haven't specified if you want to sort keys as strings or integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items()` returns `(key, value)` pairs.  `t[1]` is looking at the second part of that pair, the value.  Just do

```
expected_output=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(expected_output.items()))
```

that will give us

```
OrderedDict([('100', ['1.0']), ('101', ['0.0']), ('102', ['1.0']), ('103', ['1.0']), 
             ('104', ['0.0']), ('105', ['0.0']), ('106', ['1.0']), ('107', ['1.0']), 
             ('108', ['0.0']), ('109', ['0.0']), ('13', ['0.0']), ('14', ['8.0']), ('99', ['1.0'])])
```

If you want to sort the keys like integers rather than strings, you could do

```
expected_output=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(expected_output.items(), 
                                               key=lambda pair: int(pair[0])))
```

to get

```
OrderedDict([('13', ['0.0']), ('14', ['8.0']), ('99', ['1.0']), ('100', ['1.0']),
             ('101', ['0.0']), ('102', ['1.0']), ('103', ['1.0']), ('104', ['0.0']),    
             ('105', ['0.0']), ('106', ['1.0']), ('107', ['1.0']), ('108', ['0.0']), 
             ('109', ['0.0'])])
```